# Figure is not updating during execution of RL agent's training loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am currently working on a PPO Reinforcement learning project, using pytorch and a gymnasium custom environment. Mi idea is that every 10 training iterations, a plot with the state trajectory and actions taken by the policy is shown. The problem is that the matplotlib figure only shows properly the first time, and then is not updated for the next occasions.

The way I implemented the previously is the following: The figure is an attribute of the environment class. During the initialization of the custom class,  I call `plt.ion()` method and then initialize the fig and axes attributes calling `plt.subplots()`. After 10 iterations the axes inside the figures are cleared and plot again using the `ax[i].step()`  method. Finally I call plt.pause(0.2) and `plt.show()`. The process is repeated after the execution of the training loop.

It is likely that the problem is that I do not understand the logic of the matplotlib package very well and the solution for this problem would be change two or three lines of code. I will appreciate every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost nothing to go on, so I would suggest first showing some of the code you used and what exactly is happening.

You mention using both plt.ion and plt.show which should not be necessary as ion is an interactive mode for matplotlib which means that figures are automatically updated and plt.show does not need to be used.

Furthermore, you are using Gym. Gym has functionality build in fo rendering figures.

```py
import gym
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

env = gym.make("Taxi-v3").env

env.render()
time.sleep(10)
clear_output(wait=True)
env.render()
```